# Github branch showing in dropdown but not in branches list

Tags: github

In Github web I'm able to see an old branch in the dropdown menu (Code tab) but not in the branch list.
Even when filtering the list the branch is shown, but not when I list all branches.

Why is this happening?

The only weird thing I see, in the activity, is that the branch was deleted but received new commits after that. I suppose that a new branch with the same name was created automatically after it was deleted, but why is not in the branches list?